# Filtering Out MySQL Results Using Drop-Down Menu

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking to filter out my the names of clinic on the clinic table from a MySQL database based on the category table using a drop-down menu. any help..

Form code

```
Category :
<?php 

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","qsearch"); 

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { 
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error()); exit(); 
} 

$result = mysqli_query($con, "select CategoryName from category"); 

echo '<select id="info" name="info">'; 
echo '<option value="">-select-</option>'; 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
?> 

<option value="<?php echo $row['CategoryName']; ?>"><?php echo $row['CategoryName'];?> 
</option> 

<?php 
    } echo "</select>";
?>
```

Comment: So...????????what is the problem your facing?

Answer (score 0):

you can do thise code for easy way

```
<?php
$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "sayedsoft";
$mysql_password = "vPVJBmCTsxAHKsKF";
$mysql_database = "emlak";
$bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Could not connect database");
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Could not select database");

?>
```

and add thise function

```
function optoins_forselector($db,$name,$where) {
$result_urunler = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $db  WHERE $where");
$style_ = array();
while($result_row = mysql_fetch_array($result_urunler))
 {
  $style_[] = '<option value="'.$result_row['id'].'">'.$result_row[$name].'</option>';
 }
 return $style_;}
```

then add yor html code

```
<select name=""><?php foreach (optoins_forselector($db,$name,$where) as $option) {echo $option;} ?> </select>
```

replace $db with database name and $name colum name and if  you filitering for database do it for exp "WHERE id = '1'"

Comment: :am using this code for dispaly the full clinic list from database like wise have to to filter out the names of clinic on the clinic table from a MySQL database based on the category table using a drop-down . what is the  query for that                                         <?php
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('qsearch',$conn);

$query="select * FROM clinic";

$fetch= mysql_query("$query") or die ("couldn't select db!");

while ( $row= mysql_fetch_assoc($fetch)){

echo $row['ClinicName'] ." " ;
echo $row['Phone']."<br>";

}
?>